# Using TOP clause parametrically in joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I have joined some tables to gather some information from and I am trying to use TOP clause parametrically in SQL Server 2008 R2. Here is my code:

```
    DECLARE @num INT
    SELECT 
        TOP (@num) installTicketItem.[id] AS ItemID, it.[id], it.[usr], it.[openDate],it.[closeDate],it.[saleId],it.[ticketType],it.[ticketDesc],it.[agent],
        CASE WHEN(resultId = 3 AND usr= it.usr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fault,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM installTicket WHERE ticketType= 'modem' AND usr= it.usr AND closeDate IS Null) AND ticketType <> 'modem' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasModem, 
        CASE WHEN ((payment IS NULL) AND (installer IS NOT NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS notPaid 
    FROM installTicket it 
        JOIN (SELECT ticketId, MAX(id) AS maxID, 

        SET @num = COUNT(DISTINCT ticketId) FROM installTicketItem GROUP BY ticketId) AS iti ON iti.ticketId = it.id

        JOIN operator ON agent = username
        JOIN installPolicy ON installPolicy.agent = parentagent
        JOIN installManage ON installPolicy.panelUsr = installManage.panelUsr
        JOIN installTicketItem ON it.id = installTicketItem.ticketId
        JOIN installResult ON installResult.id = installTicketItem.resultId 

    WHERE   
        it.closeDate IS NULL AND ticketType = 'install' AND managerUsr = 'adminPanel2' AND done = 1

    ORDER BY 
        ItemID DESC, id DESC
```

I want to set `@num` parameter in a nested select as you see.

Is there any way to do that? I appreciate that if anybody could help me.

Comment: Please take a step back and explain what you want done, instead of asking how to tweak your current SQL. How do you want your query to behave?

Comment: Try the dynamic SQL approach.

Comment: You can't do it in such a way. Instead just move `SET @num = COUNT(DISTINCT ticketId) FROM installTicketItem GROUP BY ticketId` before your "main" select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi based on your question, you should use this query as

```
DECLARE @num INT

        Set @num = 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                COUNT(DISTINCT iti.ticketId) 
            FROM 
                installTicketItem  iti join  installTicket it ON iti.ticketId = it.id 
            WHERE 
                it.closeDate IS NULL AND ticketType = 'install' AND managerUsr = 'adminPanel2' AND done = 1
            GROUP BY 
                ticketId
        )

        SELECT 
            TOP (@num) installTicketItem.[id] AS ItemID, it.[id], it.[usr], it.[openDate],it.[closeDate],it.[saleId],it.[ticketType],it.[ticketDesc],it.[agent],
            CASE WHEN(resultId = 3 AND usr= it.usr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fault,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM installTicket WHERE ticketType= 'modem' AND usr= it.usr AND closeDate IS Null) AND ticketType <> 'modem' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasModem, 
            CASE WHEN ((payment IS NULL) AND (installer IS NOT NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS notPaid 
        FROM installTicket it 
            JOIN (SELECT ticketId, MAX(id) AS maxID

            --, SET @num = COUNT(DISTINCT ticketId) 
            FROM installTicketItem GROUP BY ticketId) AS iti ON iti.ticketId = it.id

            JOIN operator ON agent = username
            JOIN installPolicy ON installPolicy.agent = parentagent
            JOIN installManage ON installPolicy.panelUsr = installManage.panelUsr
            JOIN installTicketItem ON it.id = installTicketItem.ticketId
            JOIN installResult ON installResult.id = installTicketItem.resultId 

        WHERE   
            it.closeDate IS NULL AND ticketType = 'install' AND managerUsr = 'adminPanel2' AND done = 1

        ORDER BY 
            ItemID DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes it work but it causes a new problem that is increase in workload to calculate '@num' parameter. I tried to calculate it without using more commands.

Comment: you have to work on your sub query like 1. as a table you use max column , but not use in anywhere 2. in case exist condition without sub-query you can get the same thing.. try to avoid sub-query, it will effect the permormance

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged the query to make more sense, the set of a variable must be done outside the query you are trying to run it in

```
Declare @num Int;

Select @num = Count(DISTINCT ticketId) From installTicketItem; 

Select Top ( @num )
        [installTicketItem].[id] As [ItemID]
      , [it].[id]
      , [it].[usr]
      , [it].[openDate]
      , [it].[closeDate]
      , [it].[saleId]
      , [it].[ticketType]
      , [it].[ticketDesc]
      , [it].[agent]
      , Case When ( [resultId] = 3
                    And [usr] = [it].[usr]
                  ) Then 1
             Else 0
        End As [fault]
      , Case When Exists ( Select   *
                           From     [installTicket]
                           Where    [ticketType] = 'modem'
                                    And [usr] = [it].[usr]
                                    And [closeDate] Is Null )
                  And [ticketType] <> 'modem' Then 1
             Else 0
        End As [hasModem]
      , Case When ( ( [payment] Is Null )
                    And ( [installer] Is Not Null )
                  ) Then 1
             Else 0
        End As [notPaid]
From    [installTicket] [it]
        Join ( Select   [ticketId]
                      , Max([id]) As [maxID]
               From     [installTicketItem]
               Group By [ticketId]
             ) As [iti]
            On [iti].[ticketId] = [it].[id]
        Join [operator]
            On [agent] = [username]
        Join [installPolicy]
            On [installPolicy].[agent] = [parentagent]
        Join [installManage]
            On [installPolicy].[panelUsr] = [installManage].[panelUsr]
        Join [installTicketItem]
            On [it].[id] = [installTicketItem].[ticketId]
        Join [installResult]
            On [installResult].[id] = [installTicketItem].[resultId]
Where   [it].[closeDate] Is Null
        And [ticketType] = 'install'
        And [managerUsr] = 'adminPanel2'
        And [done] = 1
Order By [ItemID] Desc
      , [id] Desc;
```

In addition, you should define the type of joins you want to use

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number to parameterize top n

```
    DECLARE @num INT

--needs work, what are you doing here?
--SELECT  @num = COUNT(DISTINCT ticketId) FROM installTicketItem GROUP BY ticketId) AS iti ON iti.ticketId = it.id;  

SELECT  @num = 99;   --99 as example

    SELECT 
        installTicketItem.[id] AS ItemID, it.[id], it.[usr], it.[openDate],it.[closeDate],it.[saleId],it.[ticketType],it.[ticketDesc],it.[agent],
        CASE WHEN(resultId = 3 AND usr= it.usr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS fault,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM installTicket WHERE ticketType= 'modem' AND usr= it.usr AND closeDate IS Null) AND ticketType <> 'modem' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasModem, 
        CASE WHEN ((payment IS NULL) AND (installer IS NOT NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS notPaid 
    FROM installTicket it 
        JOIN (SELECT ticketId, MAX(id) AS maxID    --needs work, what doing here?
        JOIN operator ON agent = username
        JOIN installPolicy ON installPolicy.agent = parentagent
        JOIN installManage ON installPolicy.panelUsr = installManage.panelUsr
        JOIN installTicketItem ON it.id = installTicketItem.ticketId
        JOIN installResult ON installResult.id = installTicketItem.resultId 

    WHERE   
        it.closeDate IS NULL AND ticketType = 'install' AND managerUsr = 'adminPanel2' AND done = 1
        and ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ItemID DESC, id DESC) <= @num   -- use row_number to get top 99

    ORDER BY 
        ItemID DESC, id DESC
```